# Ace Editor, the toUpperCase function works but the toggleCommentLines does not work

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Given a webpage with an ace editor bloc (containing some code lines). On pageLoad, I want to automatically upperCase and comment the lines 1 to 2.

I instantiate the ace editor simply like this :

```js
let editor = ace.edit(editorElement); // editorElement is an html element containing some code lines
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: Infinity,
});
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
```

And this is the code executed after the pageLoad :

```js
require('ace-builds');
require('ace-builds/webpack-resolver'); // my project is managed by symfony 5 and webpack encore

let Range = require('ace-builds').Range;
editor.getSelection().setRange(new Range(0,0,2,0));

editor.toggleCommentLines(); // does nothing...why ?
editor.toUpperCase(); // its work !
// editor.clearSelection();
```

The result is :

[image]

The lines 1 and 2 are in upperCase as expected, but the lines aren't commented and I don't understand why...

I don't won't "just" add a '#' char because the mode of the generated ace editor may change. By example, the mode may be 'ace/mode/sql', and the comment in sql don't use the '#' char

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/4427#issuecomment-763415932) :)

Set the mode take a while, and its not loaded when I call  `editor.toggleCommentLines();`. The code below works for me :

```js
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/python", function() {
    editor.toggleCommentLines();
});
```

Thanks to @nightwing on the [ace git repo](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/4427#issuecomment-763415932) :)